# Render / Convert pdf in android app

Tags: android, pdf

I want to render a local stored pdf file in my android application so I can access the view.
I want to zoom the pdf and take a "screenshot" of the viewed region to add arrows and notes and save this information into a jpeg.

For me it's useless to open the pdf via intent only (with adobe pdf or similar), because I have no chance to take a shot of the viewed region in my activity.

Is there any way to include a pdf viewer or convert a pdf file into images so I can manipulate the resulted bitmaps?

I've tried iText - this won't work because of missing bouncycastle dependencies (?).

Answer (score 2):

Try [PDFViewerSDK](http://www.androidpdf.mobi/) .Very powerful and fast PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Try VuDroid https://code.google.com/p/vudroid/ or Joan Zapata's Android PdfView library https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview